# Element should remain same on window resize

Tags: html, css

I'm having a hard time fixing the issue.
My webpage consists of two **divs** with **25%** and **60%** of the width aligned side by side. The right div has cards inside (made it using Bootstrap 5).

Have a look at the following image. I want it like this in every viewport.

[image]

I want the entire UI to remain the same when the user resizes the window meaning that the width of the first div remains 25% and the second div remains 60% in all viewports. One more thing, I want to get rid of the **Display: flex** property when the window resizes so that the cards inside the div remain in a row or something else needs to be done instead of flex property.

My current display: 1920 * 1080.

I've seen many questions related to mine but I'm unable to fix this problem. Can anyone help with this one?
I am new to this platform, I hope I made it clear what my problem is.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bungee+Outline&display=swap");
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: url(/assets/bg.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  color: white !important;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: myFont;
  src: url(/assets/myFont.ttf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: mainFont;
  src: url(/assets/mainFont.otf);
}


/* .main {
 
} */

.main-row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.logo {
  height: 120px;
  width: 130px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2%;
  left: 60%;
}

.border-radius-2 {
  border-radius: 2rem !important;
}

.fs-4 {
  font-size: 4rem !important;
}

.fs-25 {
  font-size: 20px !important;
}


/* MAIN COLS */

.column {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 7rem;
}

.column:not(.col-right) {
  margin-right: 4rem;
}


/* COLUMN LEFT */

.col-left {
  width: 25%;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5242471988795518) 53%, rgba(255, 8, 24, 0.6895133053221288) 100%);
}

.rangliste {
  font-family: myFont !important;
  font-size: 75px !important;
  color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.602);
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}

.front-text {
  position: fixed;
  top: 14.5%;
  left: 14%;
  font-family: mainFont;
}

.col-left-child {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 30px !important;
}


/* COLUMN RIGHT */

.col-right {
  width: 60%;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5242471988795518) 53%, rgba(255, 8, 24, 0.6895133053221288) 100%);
  /* z-index: 9999; */
}

.col-right-child-bottom .new-row {
  --bs-gutter-x: -10.5rem !important;
}

.row-two:not(.row-one) {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.card-right-col {
  background-color: Black !important;
  border: none !important;
  border-radius: 2rem !important;
  width: 16rem !important;
  height: 18rem !important;
}

.card-right-col img {
  border-top-left-radius: 2rem !important;
  border-top-right-radius: 2rem !important;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}


/* BUTTONS */

.btn-danger {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.274) !important;
  border: none !important;
  color: red !important;
  font-weight: 600 !important;
}

.btn-red {
  padding: 0.2rem 2.5rem !important;
  border-radius: 1rem !important;
}

.card-btn {
  padding: 0 1rem !important;
  border-radius: 0.5rem !important;
}

.btn-success {
  background-color: rgba(4, 104, 4, 0.493) !important;
  border: none !important;
  border-radius: 1rem !important;
  color: rgba(5, 212, 5, 0.842) !important;
  font-weight: 600 !important;
  padding: 0.2rem 3rem !important;
}


/* ICONS */

.fa-circle {
  color: rgb(5, 212, 5) !important;
}


/* TABLE */

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 8px;
}

td {
  width: 25%;
  color: rgb(216, 212, 212);
}

td:not(:nth-child(3)) {
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.185) !important;
}

th:not(:nth-child(3)) {
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.185) !important;
}

.active-card {
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.1" />
  <title>HEX FFA</title>
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="assets/png" href="assets/logo.png">
  <!-- BOOTSTRAP 5 CDN -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <!-- FONT-AWESOME -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-Fo3rlrZj/k7ujTnHg4CGR2D7kSs0v4LLanw2qksYuRlEzO+tcaEPQogQ0KaoGN26/zrn20ImR1DfuLWnOo7aBA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <!-- LOGO -->
    <img src="assets/logo.png" class="img-fluid logo"></img>

    <div class="main-row d-flex justify-content-center">
      <!-- LEFT COLUMN -->
      <div class="column col-left border-radius-2">
        <div class="behind-text m-0">
          <h1 class="text-center rangliste m-0">RANGLISTE</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="front-text p-0 m-0">
          <h1 class="text-center rangliste-2 p-0 m-0">Rangliste</h1>
        </div>
        <!--  CHILD -->
        <div class="col-left-child border-radius-2 mt-0">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <table>
                <tr class="text-center fs-25">
                  <th>Spieler</th>
                  <th>Kills</th>
                  <th>K/D</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="text-center fs-25">
                  <td>Movas</td>
                  <td>1337</td>
                  <td>0.5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="text-center fs-25">
                  <td>Movas</td>
                  <td>1337</td>
                  <td>0.5</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="text-center fs-25">
                  <td>Movas</td>
                  <td>1337</td>
                  <td>0.5</td>
                </tr>

                <tr class="text-center">
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="text-center">
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="text-center">
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="text-center">
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="text-center">
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="text-center">
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="text-center">
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="text-center">
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="text-center">
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="text-center">
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="text-center">
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="text-center">
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="text-center">
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="text-center">
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="text-center">
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="text-center">
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="text-center">
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="text-center">
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="text-center">
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="text-center">
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="text-center">
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="text-center">
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="text-center">
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                </tr
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- LEFT COLUMN END -->

      <!-- RIGHT COLUMN -->
      <div class="column col-right border-radius-2">
        <!--  CHILD TOP -->
        <div class="container col-right-child-top">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
              <div class="card-body text-center">
                <h1 class="card-title">HEX FFA</h1>
                <h5 class="card-subtitle mb-2 ">Karte auswählen</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="button-red d-flex justify-content-end p-3 ">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-red fs-4">
                  <i class="fas fa-times"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;Schließen
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--  CHILD BOTTOM -->
        <div class="container col-right-child-bottom">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row new-row row-one">
              <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="card card-right-col border-radius-2" id="card-1">
                  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/374023/pexels-photo-374023.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
                  <div class="card-body pb-0">
                    <div class="container">
                      <div class="row ">
                        <div class="col ">
                          <h6>würfelpark</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end "> <a href="#" class="card-link"><button
                              type="button" class="btn btn-danger card-btn ">Beliebt</button></a></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="p-2 "><i class="fas fa-circle"></i>&nbsp; Spieler : 15</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="card card-right-col" id="card-2">
                  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/374023/pexels-photo-374023.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
                  <div class="card-body pb-0">
                    <div class="container ">
                      <div class="row ">
                        <div class="col ">
                          <h6>würfelpark</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end "> <a href="#" class="card-link"><button
                              type="button" class="btn btn-danger card-btn">Beliebt</button></a></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="p-2"><i class="fas fa-circle"></i>&nbsp; Spieler : 15</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="card card-right-col" id="card-3">
                  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/374023/pexels-photo-374023.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
                  <div class="card-body pb-0">
                    <div class="container ">
                      <div class="row ">
                        <div class="col ">
                          <h6>würfelpark</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end "> <a href="#" class="card-link"><button
                              type="button" class="btn btn-danger card-btn">Beliebt</button></a></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="p-2"><i class="fas fa-circle"></i>&nbsp; Spieler : 15</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row new-row row-two">
              <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="card card-right-col" id="card-4">
                  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/374023/pexels-photo-374023.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
                  <div class="card-body pb-0">
                    <div class="container ">
                      <div class="row ">
                        <div class="col ">
                          <h6>würfelpark</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end "> <a href="#" class="card-link"><button
                              type="button" class="btn btn-danger card-btn">Beliebt</button></a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="p-2"><i class="fas fa-circle"></i>&nbsp; Spieler : 15</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="card card-right-col" id="card-5">
                  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/374023/pexels-photo-374023.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
                  <div class="card-body pb-0">
                    <div class="container ">
                      <div class="row ">
                        <div class="col ">
                          <h6>würfelpark</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end "> <a href="#" class="card-link"><button
                              type="button" class="btn btn-danger card-btn">Beliebt</button></a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="p-2"><i class="fas fa-circle"></i>&nbsp; Spieler : 15</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="card card-right-col" id="card-6">
                  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/374023/pexels-photo-374023.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
                  <div class="card-body pb-0">
                    <div class="container ">
                      <div class="row ">
                        <div class="col ">
                          <h6>würfelpark</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end ">
                          <a href="#" class="card-link"><button
                              type="button" class="btn btn-danger card-btn">Beliebt</button></a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="p-2"><i class="fas fa-circle"></i>&nbsp; Spieler : 15</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="button-green d-flex justify-content-center p-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success fs-4"> <i class="fas fa-file-export"></i> &nbsp;Beitreten</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- RIGHT COLUMN END -->
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- BOOTSTRAP JS -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm facing this on window resize:
[image: These cards need to be in a row exactly the same as in the above image]

[image: The padding between the cards changes.]

Comment: you need add your html and css code to this question. It's hard to understand how you check you variant on a picture

Comment: you need to add your code to get help

Comment: Here is the link of my code:
https://codepen.io/Khushi1822/pen/YzreOoy?editors=1100

Comment: Code in the link is good to run testing but the real code should be here. Please don't link to code or use code as image. This is how they ask on StackOverflow.

Comment: Okay, thanks for guiding, I'll edit the stuff.

Comment: About width in 25% and 60% in all viewports, it is already did. When I resize to smaller screen it's keep 25% and 60% from that window size (viewport) as you want. Or... Do you mean you want overall width remain the same on all window sizes? If yes, you have to specify fixed width on outer element.

Comment: Change `col d-flex justify-content-center` to `col-4 d-flex justify-content-center` work for you?